# How to change name of element during JAXB classes generation

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have mySchema.xsd file:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="2.0">
<xs:element name="A" type="a"/>
<xs:element name="b" type="b"/>
<xs:complexType name="a">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="XXX" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Y" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Z" type="z"/>
        <xs:element name="PERSON">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="B" type="b" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="xxx" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
....
```

During classes generation in cmd console

```
"%java_home%\bin\xjc" mySchema.xsd
```

i have error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: trying to create the same field twice: xxx
```

I realized that i have the same name in xs:element name="XXX" and attribute name="xxx".
I think i should create schemat_binding.xml file and change the name of the element XXX but i dont know how.

Comment: this should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238643/how-can-i-generate-java-classes-for-xml-deserialization-using-an-xml-schema

Answer (score 0):

I wrote correct schema_bindings.xml
Maybe it will help someone:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.0" 
 jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" >

 <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd" >
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="pl.domain.jaxb.myClasses" />
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='a']//xs:attribute[@name='xxx']">
        <jxb:property name="xxxOtherName"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

And in cmd console

```
"%java_home%\bin\xjc" -b schema_bindings.xml mySchema.xsd
```