# Error: Failed to parse a schema by xjc in case of xs:choice

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I'm want to generate java classes from a schema using jaxb, but I am getting a parsing error from xjc. I have 2 elements wrapped in a choice then one of the element is again repeated just after choice:

```
<xs:element name="A">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="X"/>
        <xs:element ref="Y"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Y"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

jaxb is throwing:

```
[ERROR] Element "{*something*}Y" shows up in more than one properties.
 line *something* of file:/*something*.xsd
```

PS: my jaxb version is 2.1.13

Comment: Is your version of JAXB a "must" requirement? Can you move to the latest? I've tested with the latest available with Java 7 and it works without need to custom binding file.

Comment: no it is not a must, it's just that i am currently using 2.1.13 & in any slim case if it was a version issue of some kind, so just clearing things out.

Comment: i am sorry, but the jaxb version is not changeable.
and i am still unable to get the binding to work! help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726277/how-do-i-create-jaxb-bindings-for-docbook). The solution is to provide a custom binding file that maps your Y outside the choice to use another property name.

I would probably also map the recurring sequence to a class with two properties (X and Y), but that's something else.

I've also tried a test schema (derived from yours, just added dummy complex elements for X and Y) with version 7.1 of the free NetBeans IDE and it worked out without any need for a custom binding file. The JAXB version that I've used is 2.2.4

Comment: i have to use 2.1.13 and cannot change the version now.
and i am still facing problems with the binding, i tried to pack the sequence inside the choice in a class, but only complexType can be put inside a class. also there is no use of binding property name with different name

<jaxb:bindings node="-XPath-">
 <jaxb:property name="OutsideY"/>
</jaxb:bindings>

it is not giving any errors while reading the binding file, but not doing anything with it also! and i am sure that i have no XPath issue.

Comment: @Petru, Could you please confirm if this works in JAXB 2.2.4 ? because I tried above schema and it shows error of `[ERROR] cos-nonambig:`. I use `xjc 2.2.4-2`

Comment: EDIT: I see I use `maxoccurs` in all elements. Its ok. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've also tried to make it work as Petru described. Rahul hasn't posted his solution so here my bindings file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="test.xsd" node="//xs:element[@name='A']/xs:complexType/xs:choice[1]">
        <jaxb:property name="OutsideY"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

XJC output:

```
$xjc -version
xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6"
JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6)

$xjc -p com.example.test -d src -extension -b bindings.xml test.xsd
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
com\example\test\A.java
com\example\test\ObjectFactory.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will read this: 
org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons . jaxb2-basics is not working on references ! 
I have really tried many ways to make this plugin work, and you just can't. (It is also mentioned on github page)

@Stanislav Mamontov helped me a lot.

If somebody is curious, this also works for groups:

XSD:

```
<xsd:group name="OpticalID">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:group ref="MPCID"/>
      <xsd:element ref="trkSub" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="trkSub"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:sequence>
```

BINDING:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xsd:group[@name='OpticalID']//xsd:sequence[1]/xsd:choice[1]/xsd:sequence[1]/xsd:element[@ref='trkSub']">
    <jaxb:property name="trkSubOrNull"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```